# NumPy Polynomial Fitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, polynomials

I have the following lines of code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

x=Polynomial.fit([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4],4)
print(x)
print(x.call(0))
```

I would expect numpy to fit the data to the polynomial `f(x)=x`. But instead it outputs `2.0 + 2.0 x + (1.2915422e-15) x2 - (7.05812123e-16) x3 - (9.57512621e-17) x**4`.

Even stranger when i get it to evaluate at `x=0` it gives `1.1102230246251565e-15` which is what i would expected with `f(x)=x` but isn't `2.0`. Does anyone know what is going on?

Using the old polynomial features of numpy i.e. np.polyfit I get a correct answer but the rest of my project uses the new features.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts. I am reading the docs now and it says it returns this as a "series instance" what is it returning if it isnt the coefficents and what is convert doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs, you see that what `fit` returns is not literally the coefficients.  If you `print(x.convert().coef)`, you'll see that it is, indeed, `f(x) = x`:

```
[-1.77635684e-15  1.00000000e+00  1.22916662e-15 -3.08599735e-16
  1.95879353e-17]
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html